# Orbit slider not loading on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having an issue with an Orbit slideshow, part of ZURB's Foundation.

http://visiondemo.com.au/tmp/

If you click on the header logo or land on the homepage by clicking a link, the slideshow loads perfectly. No issues. However, if you hit refresh, it's missing.

Also, when the page is refreshed and the slideshow is missing, resizing the window makes it magically appear.

Any ideas how I can get it loading at all times?

Cheers.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Firefox 27.0.1, I do experience the same problem with Chrome (just checked). I noticed that the element `<ul class="slideshow show-for-medium-up orbit-slides-container" data-orbit="" style="height: 467px;">` has height set to 0px if I refresh by pressing F5.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the Orbit script is setting the height to 0px on load sometimes, I noticed that a few minutes ago too.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm this answer will be quite a hacky way of doing things but I think it'll work for you in a way or another..

Firstly to fix the height: 0px problem in the data-orbit.
Since you have chosen the content of your orbit to be an actual caption as well then, try to add this in a `<style>` tag or in your style.css. (#note this is only for the medium-up block only, supply your height for the small block).

```
.slideshow.show-for-medium-up > li {
    height: 421px !important;
}
```

now thats already good and working, you'll see your orbit now.. apparently another problem would appear. It would display the orbit before the content's .orbit-caption finishes styling the list. So append this small fix to your style.css

```
/* Orbit Fix */

    ul[data-orbit] {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    /* initially, hide all slides... */
    ul[data-orbit] li,
    ul[data-orbit] .orbit-caption {
        display: none;
    }

    /* ...except for the first one */
    ul[data-orbit] li:first-child { display: block; }

    /* show slides once .orbit-container is loaded */
    .orbit-container ul[data-orbit] li,
    .orbit-container ul[data-orbit] .orbit-caption {
        display: block;
    }
```

UPDATE:
I think thats because you show the image only when the screen is small, I recommend adding this,

```
.slideshow.show-for-small-only img { 
     /* change the img height here */ 
     height: 200px; /* Change this as you see fit */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The change you suggested makes the slideshow load, but now the slide becomes too small when resized smaller. See the site now if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think thats because you show the image only when the screen is small, I recommend adding this,

.slideshow.show-for-small-only img {
  /* change the img height here */
  height: 200px
}